# Can't set session property in an Express Route Middleware

Tags: session, node.js, express, middleware

I'm currently developing an API using NodeJS and Express.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret:"aaa"}));

});



function tokenLogin (req, res) {
    req.sesssion.uid = 1;
}
app.get('/api/news/:inbox', tokenLogin, function(req, res) {

});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

When I call the route `/api/news/1`, the console shows a TypeError:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'uid' of undefined
    at tokenLogin (/Volumes/Dev/a/test.js:13:19)
    at callbacks (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at param (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:243:11)
    at pass (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)
    at /Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:323:9
    at /Volumes/Dev/a/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:338:9`

Is this a bug on my code or is an ExpressJS' bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.sesssion` is a typo. You want `req.session`.

Comment: Wow, I feel completely ashamed! I had been looking for the cause for almost an hour! Thank you so much!